# Error "ImportError: no module named mux" in Python

Tags: python, importerror, mux

I installed a module one month ago. At that time, I could import the module successfully.

Now, when I import this module, there is an `ImportError`,

```
>>> import anuga
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/lili/anuga_core/source/anuga/__init__.py", line 110, in <module> from anuga.file_conversion.urs2nc import urs2nc
    File "/home/lili/anuga_core/source/anuga/file_conversion/urs2nc.py", line 12, in <module>
        from mux import WAVEHEIGHT_MUX_LABEL, EAST_VELOCITY_LABEL, \
    ImportError: No module named mux
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: What OS are you running this code on?

Comment: Look for a file named mux.py. In what directory is it located?

Comment: did you updated python to a more recent version in the meantime?

Comment: Have you gone through the Anuga installation guide (http://anuga.anu.edu.au/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/anuga_installation_guide-1.2.1.pdf)? If you're using Windows there's a step that involves adding values to the PATH environment variable in the appendix.

Comment: I use Ubuntu,I didn't find mux.py file.And I also finished to update the anuga model. DO you think it is the problem of Python? Now I am wondering if it is the problem of Python rather than Anuga.@Talvalin@furins@unutbu

Comment: Should this be tagged with ANUGA? Reference for [ANUGA](https://pypi.org/project/anuga/#id2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ImportError* comes only when the module is not available in the list called *sys.path*. Since the current operating system is Linux based (I got an idea from the error message /home/lili), it is  required to have *mux.py* in the path (i.e, *sys.path*). The *mux.py* file will be exactly similar to the file available in this link.

```
`https://anuga.anu.edu.au/svn/anuga/trunk/anuga_core/source/anuga/file/mux.py`
```

All these problems come when the installation of [ANUGA](https://pypi.org/project/anuga/#id2) is not proper.